# How to get user's IP address in a bot with node.js?

Tags: node.js, ip, http-post, bots

I am writing a bot in node.js. May I know how can I insert code to console.log the IP address of message sender please? I need the IP address to perform some auto-log in.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get ip address from request object by

`request.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! Do I just add it to my message function?

Comment: Yes in your message where there is request...post your message function if u have doubt

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time! below is the code, and by using the 'botbuilder' library of microsoft!

Answer (score 2):

> To get the Ip address of your User

```
    var app = require('express')();

    app.get("/ip", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.ip) // "::ffff:127.0.0.1" ::ffff: is a subnet prefix for IPv4 (32 bit) 
      let ip = req.ip.split(':');
      console.log(ip[3]);
       res.json(ip[3]);  // ==> 127.0.0.1 You can Get Your Ip address only 
    });
app.listen(3003);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let you know that the thing that worked for me was this:

```
server.post('/api/messages', [
    function(req,res,next){ 
        console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress); 
        next();        
    },
    connector.listen()
]);
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3316