# Finding my own Public IP Address on Java Script?

Tags: javascript, discord

I am currently using the Discord API and JavaScript to create a Discord Bot that allows my friends to start and stop a Minecraft through chat commands. I am looking for a way to send my current public IP address through to my friends. How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Your public IP address is in the header, provided that Discord gives you access to the raw request.

Comment: Refer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452028/how-to-get-users-ip-address-in-a-bot-with-node-js