# Is there a way to throttle got request to simulate server timeout?

Tags: node.js

I am troubleshooting an edge case and need a way to throttle [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) request to simulate server timeout?

Comment: Is it for unit tests or for manual tests?

Comment: Hey @Anatoly, manual tests.

Comment: Did you try to limit connection in Chrome (if you use this browser for tests) in dev tools? Or isn't it what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Refer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452028/how-to-get-users-ip-address-in-a-bot-with-node-js

Comment: Great question... this is exactly what I am looking for but for backend development.

Comment: Currently experimenting with [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) and that might work.